# Simple example get values of Jquery array in Spring Controller

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have an a JQuery array , which I want to pass on to the Spring MVC controller and insert the selected values in the database.

Inside the `$('#form').submit( function() {` function I have created and array and used the push method to insert the values into the array , like this

`

```
var Arr = [];                    
  loop ;                     
Arr.push(data)
```

`

Now I want to get this array in my Spring MVC controller and then iterate over the values to publish it to the database.

I have tried `$.postJSON("run" + 'run',Arr);` , but it does not work.

Request to please share an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.

I called an Ajax function and passed the array in data in the following format

```
`$.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "run",
                    data: ({IdArr: IdArr}),
                    success: function(html){
                      alert( "Submitted");
                        }
                  });`
```